# Why can't I reach this div?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse this page: http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=GE&region=USA&culture=en-us

When I inspect the element that I want to capture, I see that it's inside of a `<div>` with `id="data_i84"`.

However, I'm getting this:

```
irb> doc.css("#data_i84")
=> []
```

When I "view page source" and search for "`data_i84`" it doesn't show up.

Is there something I"m missing here. I thought this would be straight forward.

Comment: Is the relevant part of the page added by JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scraping Ajax data is just a matter of finding the right URL, then figuring out the proper way to parse the response:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

# you can find the ajax url in your browser's network tab, or use a debugging proxy like charles or fiddler
ajax_url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4HtmlAjax.html?&t=GE&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&view=raw&r=356282&callback=jsonp1371870522408&_=1371870527498'
response = open(ajax_url).read

# here's how you parse jsonp data
json = JSON.parse response[/{.*}/]

# the html is in a field called result
doc = Nokogiri::HTML json['result']

doc.css("#data_i84") # now you should see it.
```

Comment: what does `JSON.parse response[/{.*}/]` stand for ? Basically what does `{.*}` this do?

Comment: jsonp is json data wrapped in a function call. So it looks like this: `myfunc({"foo":"bar"})`. The regex `/{.*}/` extracts the json part.

Comment: `puts response.read` gives `jsonp1371870522408({"columnYear":"5","culture":"en-US","dataType":...` kind of output.Thus you thought about `Json` class. Is my catch right?

Comment: Kind of. Ajax responses are usually either jsonp or json and it's easy to tell the difference.